# Jboss deployment fault

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

When I try to deploy Jboss it fails. When I open server configuration I saw:

```
One or more ports have an invalid value. This may adversely affect the tooling's ability to interact with server.
```

error.

What is the problem and how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting and installing JBOSS have solved my problem.